# rxjs forkJoin Observable<never> is not assignable to parameter of type OperatorFunction<nerver>

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am making a database call for each element in my array, and storing each observables in an array, to be then completed and pass the result for further steps. 
This is what I have so far:

```
// some prior logic, it returns a list of users
   .map (users = > {
      const observables = [];
      for (let u of users) {
        //ts error: Argument of type Observable<any> is not assignable to parameter of type never
        observables.push(this.findCityAndAugmentUser(u.cityId, u))
      }
      return observables;
   }), 
   // Argument of type Observable<any> is not assignable to parameter of type OperatorFunction<never[], {}>
   forkJoin((augmentedUsers) => {
    //wait for array of augmentedUsers and do more stuff here
    console.log(augmentedUsers);
  }),

   //in short, augment the user with the model of the city
   private findCityAndAugmentUser(cityId: string, user): Observable<any> {
    return this.service.findById(cityId).pipe(
      map(city => user['city'] = city)
    )
  }
```

So the goal is to push all the observables to an array, wait for all the observables to finish and kepp working with the results. But I don't know why those signature errors I put in the comments pop out and how to fix it. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can check this other post with a similar doubt :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564164/is-there-an-operator-that-works-as-concatmap-but-with-more-than-one-inner-observ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are not returning anything from `forkJoin`. Your output observable is expecting something which is not being returned from the operator pipeline.

Try by changing your code like this:

```
.switchMap (users = > {
      const observables = [];
      for (let u of users) {
        //ts error: Argument of type Observable<any> is not assignable to parameter of type never
        observables.push(this.findCityAndAugmentUser(u.cityId, u))
      }
      return forkJoin(observables);
   }),
```

instead of map you should use switchMap (or mergeMap as per your need)to return an observable.